# MSVCRTD.lib(cpu_disp.obj) : warning LNK4210: .CRT section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators

Tags: visual-studio, linker-errors, compiler-warnings, crt

I know this question has popped up before but I could not find a good answer so I try here.

I have a pure C dll (Win32) and I get this warning when compiling:

> MSVCRTD.lib(cpu_disp.obj) : warning LNK4210: .CRT section exists;
>   there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators

Everything seems to work just fine but I am concerned about this warning since I do not understad it. I have quite a few static variables but I do not understand what ".CRT section exist" means.

What approach should I take to eliminate this warning. When I try to add the libs msdn suggests I get a ton of linker errors.

Comment: Don't ignore this warning, the CRT needs to be initialized properly with a "static initializer".  Document your linker options.

Answer (score 3):

I too had this problem; as noted when the question was asked [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/54a54fdc-f14f-4db0-b05b-986564ecd4e7), the problem was the /ENTRY:"main" which gave this error; removing that argument fixes the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by removing the `/NOENTRY` linker option.